# Why does taking more readings reduce random error?

Tags: measurements, error-analysis, statistics

So I was tossing a  coin

And I did two experiments

Experiment 1:

Tossing same Coin with no fan with different torque each time and did'nt much care about orientation of the coin, 8 times 
I got 5 T 3 H

Experiment 2:
Tossing the same coin without fan with different torque ,but same orientation of coin and Always Heads up while tossing 
I got 7 T and 1 H

I know this isn't large enough data but is the conclusion correct ??

Taking more readings and averaging reduces random errors because we start doing the experiment with the same habit thus parameters which are random become more  constant and random errors reduce ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add more trials, what actually decreases in experiments is the uncertainty on the *average* of the trial results. This is called the *law of large numbers*, and is a fundamental fact of statistics. There are various mathematical proofs of this fact, but what may be more useful is some intuition on why we should expect such a thing.

In each trial of an experiment, what you are actually doing is acquiring information about some random process. Assuming that your experiment is properly controlled, each trial will give you information about the *same* random process. In this case, the more trials you do, the more total information you have about the process. Having more information should allow you to estimate the outcome of the process more precisely. 
An average is a way of estimating the outcome of the process using all of the available information. Therefore, it should make sense that having more trials of a properly-controlled experiment should lead to a more precise average.

In your particular cases, the small number of trials means that you don't have much information about the process you're measuring. As such, the uncertainty on the probability of the coin landing on heads (which is the equivalent of an average in this situation) is going to be large. In particular, for an estimated probability $p$ taken from a sample of $n$ events, the uncertainty in the probability will be on the order of $\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}$.

For experiment 1, we have that $p=0.375\pm 0.171$. For experiment 2, we have that $p=0.125\pm0.171$. The uncertainties of these two results overlap (for example, a probability of 0.25 is within the uncertainty range of both results), and so you definitely cannot claim that there is a statistically significant difference between the two results.